# Check for updates but allow me to chose whether to install

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to configure visual studio code to check for updates but allow me to chose whether to install? And when did it *stop* behaving like this?? The August 2018 update installed without my choosing.

Answer (score 0):

On your bottom left, there is an wheel like icon, click on it to go to settings. On the search bar type update and the first results will show you "update.channel": "default", change the default to none and then restart VS Code. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for responding. So it is not clear what the exact behavior of the 'update.channel' setting is. If I set it to 'none' will it still check for updates automatically, and let me know when an update is available, but let me choose whether or not to install it? Or will it just disable check for updates completely, and I will have to manually check for an update?

Comment: With 'update.channel' set to default, it is automatically updating. I see today there is a 'restart to update' option. I don't want VS code to automatically update itself--the updates often break things. I will change 'update.channel' to 'none', and, I guess wait till next update to answer my own question.

Comment: With 'update.channel' set to none there is no update checking at all.
With 'update.channel' set to default, it checks for the update and automatically installs it.
Why would the behavior of 'default' have changed to this forcing of update?? It used to check, but give me the choice whether or not to actually install.

Comment: Still not understanding why VS Code would be designed to automatically install updates, as opposed to *automatically check for availability* of the update and let me *choose* whether to install it. Quality of updates are poor in my experience (something *always* breaks), and I have to downgrade. This time I downgraded from 1.32.3 to 1.31.1. After restarting 1.31.1 it automatically updated back to 1.32.3 smh.

Comment: Did you try my first answer?

Comment: Yes. With 'update.channel' set to none there is no update checking at all. My question is how to have vs code check for updates automatically, but allow me to chose whether to install. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I get your question now, I will check out the config file and get back to you